# What are the negative consequences of using applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate

The [documentation for `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623053-applicationdidfinishlaunching) states ...

> Although not formally deprecated, do not use this method in your apps. Use the application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) and application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) methods instead.

I was looking for any reason behind this and couldn't find anything. Are there any negative consequences for using this function?

As far as I can tell the change was made for iOS 3 (so a long long time before Swift) and the old function doesn't return anything whereas the new function returns a `Bool` so there is definitely some functional reason why to not use this function rather than just a name change.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes? I am asking "why" yes... but I'm not asking for opinions. I'm asking for concrete information about the negative consequences of using a function.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for Apple there, but if I have to guess, I think it would be to provide a common entry point whether you use a storyboard or not.
Also, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions provides you with more insight on how you've been launch (from a notification, from UITest...)

Comment: That makes sense, I might have a test around that idea to see if I can find anything concrete. Thanks

Comment: @Fogmeister: Please check out these link explaining 'launchOptions': http://nshipster.com/launch-options/

Answer (score 2):

The newer `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method has these notes about the `BOOL` return value:

> false if the app cannot handle the URL resource or continue a user activity, otherwise return true. The return value is ignored if the app is launched as a result of a remote notification.

So if you use the old `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` method it won't get information about when something went wrong. That's probably why it's not recommended.

Comment: Also makes sense. Thanks :D I'm going to have a play around with both methods and see what else I can find :D

Comment: @Fogmeister it's not stated in the docs but I see people saying that implementing the newer method prevents the older one from being called. I haven't checked to see if that's true.

Comment: Just did a quick test and that does appear to be the case :D

Answer (score -1):

Can't say the negative consequences of **applicationDidFinishLaunching(*:)*** but the added capabilities of **application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions(:)** includes

1. Use this method to complete your app’s initialisation and make any
   final tweaks.
2. This method represents your last chance to process any keys in the
   launch options dictionary.
3. Objects that are not the app delegate can access the same
   launchoptions dictionary values by observing the notification named
   uiapplicationdidfinishlaunchingnotification.
4. The return result from this method is combined with the return
   result from the application:willfinishlaunchingwithoptions: method
   to determine if a url should be handled.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application?language=objc

Comment: Yes, I saw that also. It doesn't answer the question though. Just adds another bit of the docs that say "Please don't use this". It doesn't state what the negative consequences of using it are.

Comment: Thanks for the update to the answer. It definitely makes sense to use the newer function if you need to respond to or check the launch options passed in. Would be interested to find out more about the older function and when/how it is called in the launch process. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, i should have explained in more better way(updated answer) wouldnt have resulted in downvote :(

Comment: Well you have an update from me after the updates. Maybe others will remove their down votes in the future. Thanks for the answer though :D

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister for the update, Well waiting for others to re-cast their votes